# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Not found

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been receiving the following email since Sept 1 .
Prior to that I had set up Gmail Meter in Google Docs/Drive but deleted the spreadsheet.
How can I stop receiving the emails .

**Your script, Not found, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
9/3/12 10:21 PM activityReport  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.  time-based  9/3/12 10:21 PM
Sincerely,
Google Apps Script**

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that helped me:

Go to script.google.com. Go to "Resource" -> "All your triggers".

A rename dialogue should pop up prompting you to save this fake script. Click Ok.

Try to find the trigger that's sending the email and delete it.

Now all your triggers should appear - even for documents that you've already deleted from Google Docs/Drive.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a trigger that is still in your trigger list, to remove it simply open any script in the script editor and go to /ressources/all your triggers/ and delete it.[image]

Comment: I reinstalled Gmail Meter and then deleted it . That fixed the problem.