# how to delete a script from already deleted file

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the email I've been getting for a while "Your script, add reminder zv, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here."

I already deleted the file in question (from the trash folder). How can I deactivate the script at this point and stop receiving related emails.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this post [Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278310/summary-of-failures-for-google-apps-script-not-found/12284480#12284480). And follow the procedure as described.

Answer (score 0):

Click the link in the error email that says "Click here" and remove the trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Click here gets me to "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."

Comment: Go to your [Google Account](http://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and revoke access to the script / document.