# Getting "Google Apps Script" "The script doesn't have permission to perform that action." randomly

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I have a script that runs every 5 minutes on Google Apps Script and sometimes (once a month), I receive an email with:

Your script, xxx, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
8/9/18 7:32 PM  xxx The script doesn't have permission to perform that action. Required permission: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/) (line 17, file "Code") time-based  8/9/18 7:33 PM

How come it complains only randomly. Rest of the time works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the workaround given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278310/summary-of-failures-for-google-apps-script-not-found).

> Go to script.google.com. Go to "Resource" -> "All your triggers".
>
> A rename dialogue should pop up prompting you to save this fake
>   script. Click Ok.
>
> Try to find the trigger that's sending the email and delete it.
>
> Now all your triggers should appear - even for documents that you've
>   already deleted from Google Docs/Drive.

There may be a trigger that is still in your trigger list. To remove it, simply open any script in the script editor and go to /resources/all your triggers/ and delete it.